I want to get the SHA1 key of my project on android studio
Task 'signingReport' not found in root project 'chatting' and its subprojects.

Try:


Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.
For more on name expansion, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:name_abbreviation in the Gradle documentation.
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 328ms

I was supposed to get access to the signingReport but it is suggested that signingReport is not found in my root project. What should I do to amend?

Here is how you can get signing report which contains SHA-1 Key:
1: First Go to the terminal in left-bottm corner of android studio(Image has been provided as well).
2: Write following command:
./gradlew signingReport
3: Wait for a while and you will have your signing report with all keys including SHA-1 key:


This is not working.

Open your android folder on Android studio..

Go to Settings
On the Experimental section check Configure all Gradle tasks during Gradle Sync and apply the change
Now on the top right corner clic on Sync project with Gradle files
After that open the Gradle panel and clic on Execute Gradle task and search for signingReport and enter

Hope that help..

I did this but it is still not working. Still the signingReport is not found.

Open terminal or command prompt.
Navigate to your project directory.
Run the command:
./gradlew signingReport

This command is for Windows
gradlew signingReport.

I hope it will be easy now to get sha1 and sha256,

Open project on android studio than tap on ctrl key twice than run anything will appear after that copy ./gradlew signingReport and paste you will get the SHA key
